# Construindo uma api rest para recuperar dados de uma base usando spring batch

Tags: java, spring-mvc, batch

Estou tentando construir uma api rest para recuperar dados de uma tabela, usando spring batch.

Abaixo meu serviço rest:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE + ";charset=UTF-8")
public List<Deposit> requestJob1() throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException, NoSuchJobException, JobParametersNotFoundException, UnexpectedJobExecutionException {
    
    jobLauncher.run(jdbcCursorReaderJob, new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("uniqueness", System.nanoTime()).toJobParameters());
    
    return ?
```

Abaixo meu reader:

```
@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<Deposit> jdbcCursorReader(
        @Qualifier("datasource") DataSource dataSource) {
    
    return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Deposit>()
            .name("jdbcCursorReader")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .sql("select * from depositos")
            .rowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Deposit>(Deposit.class))
            .build();
}
```

Abaixo meu writer:

```
public class JdbcCursorWriterConfig implements ItemWriter<Deposit> {

    List<Deposit> output = TransactionAwareProxyFactory.createTransactionalList();

    public void write(List<? extends Deposit> items) throws Exception {
        output.addAll(items);
    }

    public List<Deposit> getOutput() {
       return output;
    }

}
```

Minhas dúvidas são:

1 - Acho que meu writer está errado. Como exatamente devo escrever meu writer?
2 - Como devo manipular o retorno do meu writer no método rest requestJob1?

Answer (score 2):

Tem alguns pontos que a gente precisa levar em consideração

1 - O Spring Batch não vai te retornar os valores que ele fez o processamento. Vale a pena a gente lembrar que os processamentos batches foram criados pra trabalhar com uma grande quantidade de dados, dependendo da quantidade de dados não é muito complicado de você trafegar com ela na rede. Eu já trabalhei com processos que trabalhavam com centenas de milhões de dados várias vezes ao dia.

2 - Se você for somente utilizar o batch para fazer uma consulta no banco e te retornar os valores, eu não utilizaria o batch. É muito melhor você recuperar eles direto do banco e retornar na sua resposta.

3 - Não é legal você deixar sua requisição esperando a finalização do processamento para devolver os registros processados. O ideia é você no requestJob1 devolver o status do job, ou que ele foi iniciando, deixar ele executando de forma async e depois ir onde você salvou esses dados e recuperar.

Agora se sua ideia é transformar esses dados, ler de algum arquivo e salvar em banco, fazer sincronização entre diferentes bancos, ai sim seria legal a utilização de batch para isso. Depois é só você criar um serviço que recupera esses dados pra você.

Só pra finalizar, eu acho que devemos utilizar o batch por chamada rest, somente para start do job.